# How to move a project to a new SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

What's the best/easiest/fastest way to move a project from a local copy to a new repository?

The machine hosting the original repository died and I am in the process of recreating a repo on a new machine from local copies.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that all the clients are Windows machines and only one has cygwyn (to support the `rm` command.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everyone here is suggesting to delete the svn folders.  SVN has a "export" command to make a copy of the folder without the .svn folders, which is ready for import later.

Comment: Would this not require a connection to the repo -- which is now gone -- in order to work?  (cvs export pulls from the repo, is svn export any different?)

Comment: Thanks Marc. This was by far the cleanest suggestion and the one i ended up following. The reason i won't upvote other answers is that they only accounted for the .svn folders and also assumed the availability of an rm command. There are many folders and files that need to be "cleaned" out before a proper import can be made and which the Tortoise export takes care of. (bin folders for example.)

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf `find . -name .svn`
svn import [...]
```

Of course, you'll have not history, since your original repo died, and you must not have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the source to a new location, remove all the .svn subdirectories.  Import the net result.

Answer (score 0):

If the original repository is dead, then you have lost the history. The best thing to do is delete the .svn directories in the tree (rm -rf `find ./ -iname .svn`) and re-import the source onti a new repository created on the new server